# Can't copy, move, rename files that have special character (single quote) in their file names

Tags: command-line, special-characters

I have some files that have the special character `'` in their file names. I seem to not able to copy, move, rename those files.

For example, when I try to rename `grandpa's_pen.mp4` to `grandpas_pen.mp4`, the action takes too much time.

The size of the files is about 50MB and my hard disk is NVMe.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [escape](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html) `'`, since, as you have also mentioned, single quotes (`'`) are special characters in Bash (which is most likely the shell your terminal uses). To escape a character you can use [the escape character `\`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Escape-Character.html) right in front of it. So, for example, to rename `grandpa's_pen.mp4` to `grandpas_pen.mp4` you should run:

```
mv grandpa\'s_pen.mp4 grandpas_pen.mp4
```

Alternatively, you can use double quotes (`"`) around the files that have single quotes. The above example would be in that case:

```
mv "grandpa's_pen.mp4" grandpas_pen.mp4
```

---

**Note:**

You said:

> For example, when I try to rename `grandpa's_pen.mp4` to `grandpas_pen.mp4`, the action takes too much time.

In this case that action does not take too much time. Simply, *the command has not even run!*

That's because when single quotes and double quotes are used as special characters, that is when they are used without being escaped, they are expected by the shell to be in pairs.

In your case, `grandpa's_pen.mp4` has one unescaped single quote, so when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run your command, the shell gives you a new prompt, in which you could type more text, and waits until you enter a closing single quote. Only if you enter that closing single quote and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> will the command run, which is almost certain to return an error.